# Inserting multiple columns in Cassandra

Tags: c++, nosql, cassandra

How can I insert multiple Columns for one row using one insert() in C++? I'm using the thrift generated cpp code.

I noticed the Java implementation seems to have a batch_insert(), which doesn't exist in the cpp generated code. Does that mean I have to call insert() for each column or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thrift interface has a `batch_mutate()` call that allows you to pass in a map of mutations--a mutation being any insert or delete.

From the Thrift spec:

```
/**
Mutate many columns or super columns for many row keys. See also: Mutation.
mutation_map maps key to column family to a list of Mutation objects to take place at that scope.
  **/
void batch_mutate(1:required map<binary, map<string, list<Mutation>>> mutation_map,
                  2:required ConsistencyLevel consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
     throws (1:InvalidRequestException ire, 2:UnavailableException ue, 3:TimedOutException te)
```